# remove all CSS image style but keep html attributes (width and height)

Tags: html, css, laravel-5

i am storing html text in the database for example:

```
<p><img title="dasdasd" src="storage/posts/April2017/lKZCxXpP.jpg" alt="asdasd" width="100" height="100"/></p>
```

and then in another page i am displaying this text as html, consider it as a post body that need to be displayed with formatting.

the problem is that i am using a template that contain a lot of styling.
in the style.css i have

```
img {  max-width: 100%;   height: auto;   width: 100%; }
```

its from the template styling and i cannot change this because it will mess up all my template.

**the problem**

the template styling is overriding the style of the image `width ="100" height="100"` that is stored with the html in the database, so i need the image to use the width and height that are provided by the creator of the post and stored in the database.

i already tried

```
height: unset;  width: unset;
```

but it will revert back the image to its original size not the one provided by the post creator.

is there anything i can do beside changing all the img style of themplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry reposting my answer for better formatting lol

So if you have more then one this would be the way:

```
<?php
$foo = '<p>
<img title="img 1" src="https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/sitepoint/community/user_avatar/www.sitepoint.com/paulob/45/44116_1.png" alt="asdasd" width="100" height="100"/>
<img title="img 2" src="https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/sitepoint/community/user_avatar/www.sitepoint.com/paulob/45/44116_1.png" alt="asdasd" width="200" height="200"/>
</p>';

$pattern = '/width="(\d+)"\s+height="(\d+)"/';
$replacement = 'style="width:$1;height:$2;"';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $foo);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

css always gives more priority to inline styles, so store the string in db like this

```
<p><img title="dasdasd" src="storage/posts/April2017/lKZCxXpP.jpg" alt="asdasd" style="width:100; height:100;" /></p>
```

and by the way simple way to retrieve images, good ideology  u can even make simpler by just storing location of image and putting img tag using js

i hope this might help you

Comment: Hey Shantosh, thanks for the reply.
the thing is that we are a team and we are using voyager on top of laravel, and we are using the voyager default post creator and i am not allowed to override it, so i cannot control how the post is saved :( 
so in another case this would solve my isuue

Comment: Is it Working ?

Comment: @Ketchup good idea but in these scenarios we need language that can edit files on the server. So PHP to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the width and height of the HTML string and add a style attribute that equals that directly on the image. Add !important to it so that it becomes the default.

```
<?php

    $foo = '<p><img title="dasdasd" src="storage/posts/April2017/lKZCxXpP.jpg" alt="asdasd" width="100" height="100"/></p>';
    $parsedFoo = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($foo)), true);
    $newFoo = str_replace('src=', 'style="height:'.$parsedFoo['@attributes']['height'].'!important;width:'.$parsedFoo['@attributes']['width'].'!important;" src=', $foo);

?>
```

Comment: hello WebiumMedia
thanks for the reply. would this work if i have more than one image in same stored data?

Comment: just tried to test it
`simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document`

Comment: No in that case you will have to do somathing like this:
    <?php
    $foo = '<p>
    <img title="img 1" src="[URL]" alt="asdasd" width="100" height="100"/>
    <img title="img 2" src="[URL]" alt="asdasd" width="200" height="200"/>
    </p>';
    
    $pattern = '/width="(\d+)"\s+height="(\d+)"/';
    $replacement = 'style="width:$1;height:$2;"';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $foo);
    ?>

Comment: Please view my other answer